# converting a drawable to a bitmap giving me an error

Tags: android, bitmap, android-context

i want to convert a drawable from an object to a bitmap, but when i try to use this

```
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), 
    cardWriter.getCardImage());
```

it gives me an error wrong second argument expecting 'int' found 'drawable' but everything i read says it should take a drawable. When i begin to write cardWriter.getCardImage() android studios code completion says its a drawable, 
this is from my CardWriters class

```
  public CardWriter(Drawable cardImage, String cardEmotion, String 
  speechText)
{
    this.cardImage = cardImage;
    this.cardEmotion = cardEmotion;
    this.speechText = speechText;

}
```

i think it may be my context thats wrong but i dont see how as its just a method that i pass the context too, heres the full thing

```
 public void insertCardDetails(Context context, CardWriter cardWriter) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), cardWriter.getCardImage());
    cv.put(CARD_PHOTO, Utility.getBytes(bitmap));
    cv.put(CARD_NAME, cardWriter.getCardEmotion());
    cv.put(CARD_SPEECH, cardWriter.getSpeechText());
    IconsDB.insert(EMPLOYEES_TABLE, null, cv);
}
```

what am i not doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BitmapFactory.decodeResource` expects a drawable id for the second parameter.

You should do:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.your_drawable_id);
```

Or if you don't know the id:

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)cardWriter.getCardImage()).getBitmap;
```

Comment: Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable)cardWriter.getCardImage()).getBitmap();      worked perfectly thank you very much

Comment: What is cardWriter. I would also like to get a drawable from imageView and convert it to bitmap image. How can I do it